# Can you left factor this grammar, whose production bodies have no common prefixes?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, grammar, context-free-grammar, computation-theory

The grammar is as follows:

```
R -> R + T | T
T -> T F | F
F -> F * | P
P -> a | b
```

Terminals: `{+, *, a, b}`

Non-terminals: `{R, T, F, P}`

My understanding is that as there are no common prefixes among the alternatives for any of the nonterminals, this grammar cannot be left factored.

For example, `R` has alternatives `R + T` and `T`, and neither of these share a common prefix.

Is my understanding correct?

I tried eliminating left recursion first, to see if the result could be left factored. But this doesn't seem to be the case:

```
R  -> T R'
R' -> + T R' | ε
T  -> F T'
T' -> F T' | ε
F  -> P F'
F' -> * F' | ε
P  -> a | b
```

Comment: Your left-recursion elimination is far from correct. (Where's the `*`, for example?)

Comment: @rici I think I've fixed the left recursion elimination now.

Comment: If there are no common prefixes, there's no need to left-factor.  Left-factoring is for removing common prefixes, and if there are none, doing a "left-factoring" algorithm on the grammar will have no effect.